# Windows 10 VPN connection, but webpage not loading and works on Andriod

Tags: windows-10, vpn, dynamic-dns, webpage

I'm tring to connect to a dyndns.org through a VPN
The server side works and it works perfect with Andriod.
With Windows 10 it takes a bit, but says is connected without any mention of problems, it takes a long time to load a webpage and then doesn't load it.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: do you have anymore detail?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the built-in VPN or a third party VPN? Is it available to access other websites?

If you are using a third party VPN, please ensure you have got Windows 10 compatible version. We could try to reinstall it to have a troubleshoot.

If you are using the built-in VPN, please ensure other machines use the same VPN could connect to the website and ensure you could use the VPN resources.
We may need to untick the "Use default gateway on remote network" option.
1.Double-click My Computer, and then click the Network and Dial-up Connections link.

2.Right-click the VPN connection that you want to change, and then click Properties.

3.Click the Networking tab, click Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) in the Components checked are used by this connection list, and then click Properties.

4.Click Advanced, and then click to clear the Use default gateway on remote network check box .

5.Click OK, click OK, and then click OK.

Comment: We use the same build in Windows 10 set-up. Windows 7 has the same problem. It seems to be a dns lookup ipv4 / ipv6 problem. With Windows 7 I could google and check with what is my ip that the ip is the good one, but other pages don't load. Changing metrics didn't work and uncheck the default gateway brings me back to my own ip / connection. Pinging and nslookup worked and was fast.